# Table column width equal to content width

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a table

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Order Dat</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cakes</td>
            <td>100 $</td>
            <td>2015-01-09</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Clouthing for Sping</td>
            <td>20000 $</td>
            <td>2015-02-09</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want my second column (Prices) to be the exact size of its header length or the longest content length in its column. I don't want it, the second column, to have that 'invisible white space' that the browser adds to the column, to make the table wider.

What I have already tried:

1. Setting Default % or px width. This is not suitable for me, since I don't know how long will my data be.
2. Setting table width not to 100%. This is the reason, that causes the table to stretch and add those 'white spaces' to my columns. The problem is that I need my table to be 100%, I just want **one of my columns** NOT to be stretched.

P.s. I'm also using bootstrap. (don't know if that helps)

EDIT:

Pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSAcR.jpg

Comment: Can you post screenshots? I ask this because normally a table will only grow in size if the contents demand it to; so it should always perfectly fit its contents if you (or bootstrap) don't alter this default behaviour.

Comment: @klaar Added. As you can see the Price column has a lot of aditional space. I want ALL of it out.

Comment: The column you want to be your main one, looks like name, needs to have its width set to 100%, that will force all remaining width in all columns to be funneled into that one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will want to set the column that you want the extra width to go into to have its with of 100%. This won't actually make it a true 100%, it will just force it to be a big as possible. This will make other columns wrap though to fit that need so make sure you set the white space property to no wrap.

The CSS

```
.table {
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nameCol {
    width:100%;
}
.table td {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

The HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="nameCol">Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Order Dat</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cakes</td>
            <td>100 $</td>
            <td>2015-01-09</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Clouthing for Sping</td>
            <td>20000 $</td>
            <td>2015-02-09</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/q16dp8ja/1/

Additional notes, I also added some left right padding for readabilities sake since the columns will now be narrower on the right, also you should pick a different class than `.table` as it can be easily confused with `table` the element selector.

Comment: this is almost what I want!. Just a small but tho. Let's say that the Date column will have it's date written with spaces: 2015 02 09. Your method will break the column into 3 rows. Is it possible not to do that ?

Comment: nevermind, I found this thing called 'white-space: nowrap'.

Comment: This is quite a nasty hack that might introduce unwanted side-effects, since this is not the intended use of `width: 100%;`, but if it suits your context, then fine.

Comment: @klaar actually it's a very common usage, Though I mostly use DIVs now and days this fix is very browser compatible back to early IE days and Ive yet to see a layout break because of it.

Comment: @Stralos the no wrap is mentioned in the answer and implemented in the code samples above.

Comment: I'm very unpragmatic in this matter, that's why I'd rather find a more elegant solution. But if this tactic is tried & proven, then you have my blessing. Not that you'd need it.

Comment: Only caveat is the nowrap property can break the name column if you have an exceptionally large product name, but the fix to that is easy as well, instead of applying nowrap to the entire table, only apply it to the columns with the price and date.